# Jointly strictly convex vs. marginally strictly convex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose $f(x,y)$ is (jointly) convex in $(x,y)$ and strictly convex in each argument separately. Is it necessarily true that $f$ is jointly strictly convex? Here, $x,y$ live in some real vector spaces.

Answer (score 3):

No. Consider
$$
f(x,y) = (x-y)^2.
$$

Comment: thanks! a counterexample was eluding me